# unable to deploy docker application in elasticbeanstalk using travis ci

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy docker application in AWS elastic beanstalk from travis CI.

Travis CI not showing error but when i am deploying the application in elastic beanstalk it showing below error in the logs.

2020/04/27 02:03:14.074446 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker pull node:alpine as builder, retrying...

2020/04/27 02:03:14.074466 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder

**2020/04/27 02:03:14.118181 [ERROR] "docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.**

**2020/04/27 02:03:14.118209 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:"docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.**

below is my github repository kindly check if possible and let me know if i am doing something wrong.

https://github.com/abtayshete06/docker-react.git

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue while trying to deploy docker application in elasticbeanstalk. It seems the issue is with platform selected while creating the environment.

If you select the platform "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2" this issue is reproduced.

To solve this you can select the platform option " Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux" instead. I tried this and issue was resolved.

The same is answered in this thread 
[AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker Does not support Multi-Stage Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518512/aws-elastic-beanstalk-docker-does-not-support-multi-stage-build)